# sort and hide duplicate fields table angular 4+

Tags: html

I want to sort the table by name and first name and if we find duplicate fields we leave one line by adding an accordion to show duplicates or masked.
I put the ts and html code

Comment: hi minouch and welcome to Stackoverflow, could you tell us more about your "sortable" functionality ? is it self made or you use 3th party library for doing that ?

Comment: hi jason , how are you?
it's self made with a mock service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have create this sample for you, i have remove `Observable` to simplify the code :

First i have create new structure with some meta data information.
`isFirst` and `isExpended` are useful on html side to manage "hide/show" state of related Clients.

```
export interface OrderedClient {
  isUniq: boolean;
  isFirst: boolean;
  isExpended: boolean;
  info: Client;
}
```

I have put dummy data on constructor to show you how to classify this:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  private clients: Client[];
  displayClients: OrderedClient[];
  constructor() {
    this.clients = [
        {id: 1, lastname: 'git',firstName: 'yanis', birthDate:'03/19/1990'},
        {id: 2, lastname: 'git',firstName: 'yanis', birthDate:'01/01/1990'},
        {id: 3, lastname: 'lorem',firstName: 'yanis', birthDate:'01/01/1990'}
    ];
    this.classify();
  }

  private classify() {
    this.displayClients = [];
    // For each existing clients.
    this.clients.forEach((client: Client) => {
      // We create new structure describe by OrderedClient interface.
      this.displayClients.push(
        // We merge client and getInformation output.
        Object.assign({
          info: client
          },this.getInformation(client))
        );
    });
  }

  private getInformation(client: Client): {
    isFirst: boolean,
    isUniq: boolean,
    isExpended: boolean
  } {
    // We fetch all clients who have same first and last name.
    const clients = this.clients.filter(current => {
        return current.lastname === client.lastname && current.firstName === client.firstName;
    });
    // We create meta information
    return {
      // If is first item of list.
      isFirst: clients[0].id === client.id,
      // if he is alone.
      isUniq: clients.length === 1,
      // If he is visible by default.
      isExpended: clients.length === 1 || clients[0].id === client.id
    };
  }

  toggleRelated(client:Client) 
  {
      //When we click on toggle button. we loop on all clients.
      this.displayClients.forEach(e => {
          // If current one have same first and last name and is not the first element of associated clients.
          if(e.info.firstName === client.firstName && e.info.lastname === client.lastname && !e.isFirst) {  
            // Then we toggle expended state.
            e.isExpended = !e.isExpended;
          }
      });
  }
}
```

for each clients, i will check if we can find similar other entry on document. Goal is to populate `isFirst` and `isExpended`. Now we can use this new structure on our html as bellow :

```
<div class="m-table" data-module="scrollable">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th sortable-column="lastname" scope="col">Nom<a href="#" class="a-order a-order-check">trie</a></th>
        <th sortable-column="firstname" scope="col">Prénom<a href="#" class="a-order">trie</a></th>
        <th scope="col">Date de naissance<a href="#" class="a-order">trie</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of displayClients">
        <tr *ngIf="data.isExpended">
          <td><button *ngIf="data.isFirst && !data.isUniq" (click)="toggleRelated(data.info)">toggle</button></td>
          <td scope="col">{{data.info.lastname}}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{data.info.firstName}}</td>
          <td scope="col">{{data.info.birthDate}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[online sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kajqbh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thank you yanis i wanana see and tell you if it work

Comment: hi yanis, well, it's working awesomely.
i think a had a lack somewhere in the begining, so i updated it as you showed me and it worked.
Thumb up my friend !

Comment: Super, i happy if this answer have help you. Happy coding @minouch

Comment: je vous ai rajouter sur linkedin , je veux bien rester en contact avec vous .

Answer (score 0):

You can "map" your result, adding a property to check if is repeated, but first of all you must ordered the array

```
this.searchService.getAllClients()
      .subscribe(results =>{
        //first sort
        results.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.lastname + a.firstname == b.lastname + b.firstname ? 0 :
                   a.lastname + a.firstname > b.lastname + b.firstname ? 1 : -1;
        //After, map the result adding a new propertie
        this.results=result.map((x) => {
            return {...x, uniq: results.find(
             f => f.lastname + f.firstname == x.lastname + x.firstname) == x }
      })
      ),
      error =>console.log('results', error );
```

Notice, I use this.result.find that return an element. if this element is equal so self, is the first one of them

Comment: hi Eliseo ,
thak you for your answer but he dosn't work

Comment: @minouch was an error when I'used find -yet corrected- it's NOT this.result.find, is result.find